# Proof of the zeros of a holomorphic function being isolated

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen the proof of this theorem and for the most part I able able to follow the argument, there is just one small piece which I am having difficulty accepting. That part is, since $f$ is not identically zero and is holomorphic we can write

$$ f(z) = (z-z_0)^n [a_n + a_{n+1}(z-z_0) + \cdots] = (z-z_0)^n g(z)$$

for the smallest integer $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0$.

The claim is that $g$ must also be nowhere vanishing for all $z$ close to $z_0$ since $a_n \neq 0$. However, how does this ensure that for some $z'$ we don't have
$$ a_n = -a_{n+1}(z'-z_0) + \cdots$$

From here my understanding is analytic continuation wraps up the rest of the theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is a continuous (in fact holomorphic, but this extra bit is irrelevant here) function such that $g(z_0)=a_n\neq 0$. So, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<\delta$ then $|g(z)-g(z_0)|<\frac{|g(z_0)|}{2}$ (this is just the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity of $g$ at $z_0$ with $\epsilon=\frac{|g(z_0)|}{2}$). So, by the reverse triangle inequality, it follows
\begin{align}
|g(z_0)|-|g(z)|\leq |g(z)-g(z_0)|<\frac{|g(z_0)|}{2}
\end{align}
So, rearranging yields
\begin{align}
0<\frac{|g(z_0)|}{2}<|g(z)|
\end{align}
i.e $g$ doesn't vanish on the open disc $\{z\in\Bbb{C}\,:\, |z-z_0|<\delta\}$. Thus, for $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, we have $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ being the product of two non-zero numbers, and thus is non-zero; i.e the zero $z_0$ of $f$ is isolated.

---

In short, if a continuous function is non-zero at a point, there there is a neighborhood of that point on which it is still non-zero.

Comment: Ah so it follows from continuity, that makes sense. Thank you very much!